# How to delete a tuple in a list in a list:

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list

```
dist= [[(0.0, 1.0)], [(20.0, 0.8563799085248148)], [(40.0, 0.8371216462519347)], [(60.0, 0.9282032302755089)], [(80.0, 7.8429970322236064), (80.0, 1.2045483557883576)], [(100.0, 3.753460385470896), (100.0, 2.070863609380179)], [(120.0, 2.6794919243112276), (120.0, 12.92820323027545)], [(140.0, 2.298981118867903)], [(160.0, 2.250827351906659)], [(180.0, 2.4999999999999996), (180.0, 6.000000000000004)], [(200.0, 3.2523178818773006), (200.0, 3.0522653889161626)], [(220.0, 5.622391569468206), (220.0, 2.226834844885431)], [(240.0, 37.32050807568848), (240.0, 1.9366857335569074)], [(260.0, 1.9181147622136665)], [(280.0, 2.1576718089133085)], [(300.0, 2.85976265663383)], [(320.0, 2.9627929206431776), (320.0, 5.162096782237789)], [(340.0, 1.4051274947736847), (340.0, 69.47032761621178)]]
```

Notice that I have some elements in the list that share a first element (Sorry for incorrect terminology.) For example, `dist[4]` is `[(80.0, 7.8429970322236064), (80.0, 1.2045483557883576)]`; and the 80 is in both tuples.

Now I want to delete the tuple whose `tup[1]` element is larger. So in this case, I want to delete `(80.0, 7.8429970322236064)` because 7.84299... is larger than 1.20454....

After the process is completed, `dist[4]` would only be `[(80.0, 1.2045483557883576)]`

I've tried something like this

```
for e in range(len(dist)):
    if len(dist[e]) >= 2:
            for f in range(len(dist[e])):
                del max(dist[e][f])
```

But it returns this:

```
>SyntaxError: can't delete function call
```

Comment: `max(dist[e][f])` is a float, where are you checking for common first elements?

Comment: Based on the input, it looks like he forgot to mention that when the tuples were together in a sublist, they have the same first element.

Comment: Can you clarify - should tuples only be removed if they have a common first element? Or will they always have a common first element if they are in an inner list together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[min(l)] for l in dist]
```

does the job, because min works fine on tuples: `(80,1)<(80,2)`.

Comment: This compares every element instead of just the second which would make a big difference if the sublists were large

Comment: I think it's lazy evaluation. It seems to be faster then a call to itemgetter :   

%timeit [[min(l,key=itemgetter(1))] for l in dist]
-> 22.7 µs  ;  %timeit [[min(l)] for l in dist] ->  9.62 µs

Answer (score 1):

Import `operator` to supply compare function to min.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
```

Iterate over the list and for each item which is also a list, get the minimum of it according to second element.

```
>>> [min(e, key=itemgetter(1)) for e in dist]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain more of what this does; maybe even walk through an example?

Comment: @DNA Aren't there 2 `(` before it and one `)` before it too?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham right, I did it according to example. I guess wording in the question was wrong/misleading.

Comment: If you use `dist[:] = [min(e, key=itemgetter(1)) for e in dist]` you will modify the original list

Answer (score 1):

```
dist= [[(0.0, 1.0)], [(20.0, 0.8563799085248148)], [(40.0, 0.8371216462519347)], [(60.0, 0.9282032302755089)], [(80.0, 7.8429970322236064), (80.0, 1.2045483557883576)], [(100.0, 3.753460385470896), (100.0, 2.070863609380179)], [(120.0, 2.6794919243112276), (120.0, 12.92820323027545)], [(140.0, 2.298981118867903)], [(160.0, 2.250827351906659)], [(180.0, 2.4999999999999996), (180.0, 6.000000000000004)], [(200.0, 3.2523178818773006), (200.0, 3.0522653889161626)], [(220.0, 5.622391569468206), (220.0, 2.226834844885431)], [(240.0, 37.32050807568848), (240.0, 1.9366857335569074)], [(260.0, 1.9181147622136665)], [(280.0, 2.1576718089133085)], [(300.0, 2.85976265663383)], [(320.0, 2.9627929206431776), (320.0, 5.162096782237789)], [(340.0, 1.4051274947736847), (340.0, 69.47032761621178)]]
from operator import itemgetter
for sub in dist:
    if len(sub) > 1:
        mx = max(sub,key=itemgetter(1))
        sub.remove(mx)

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(dist)

[[(0.0, 1.0)],
 [(20.0, 0.8563799085248148)],
 [(40.0, 0.8371216462519347)],
 [(60.0, 0.9282032302755089)],
 [(80.0, 1.2045483557883576)],
 [(100.0, 2.070863609380179)],
 [(120.0, 2.6794919243112276)],
 [(140.0, 2.298981118867903)],
 [(160.0, 2.250827351906659)],
 [(180.0, 2.4999999999999996)],
 [(200.0, 3.0522653889161626)],
 [(220.0, 2.226834844885431)],
 [(240.0, 1.9366857335569074)],
 [(260.0, 1.9181147622136665)],
 [(280.0, 2.1576718089133085)],
 [(300.0, 2.85976265663383)],
 [(320.0, 2.9627929206431776)],
 [(340.0, 1.4051274947736847)]]
```

Comment: That didn't work for at least the 120.0 line and the 340.0 line. Thanks for your help, though. :)

Comment: @FredBarclay, I passed the wrong key the code works, are the first elements always the same when you have pairs of tuples?

Comment: 1. The code's working! I feel stupid. :) 2. Yes, the first element will always be the same. This is examining the distance between the intersection point of a ray with a line (sort-of) and a point at the source of the ray. The angle of the ray is the first element of the set, and sometimes the same ray intersects 2 lines (so the angle of the ray will be the same, but the distance will be different.) When this occurs, I only need the closest distance.

Comment: @FredBarclay,you simply need to just find the max and remove it then , also instead of adding you could probably do the filtering before you add a second tuple keeping the one with the smallest value at an earlier step.

Comment: I'm thinking of eliminating them earlier too. It would certainly save a bit of time.

Comment: Well no point adding to remove them later if you are never going to use them.

Answer (score 0):

with deep iteration :)

```
for pairs in dist:
    if len(pairs)>1:
            for tuples in pairs:
                    if sum(tuples[0])>sum(tuples[1]): 
                        tuples.remove(tuples[0])
                    else: 
                        tuples.remove(tuples[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution using `reduce`:

```
dist= [[(0.0, 1.0)], [(20.0, 0.8563799085248148)], [(40.0, 0.8371216462519347)], [(60.0, 0.9282032302755089)], [(80.0, 7.8429970322236064), (80.0, 1.2045483557883576)], [(100.0, 3.753460385470896), (100.0, 2.070863609380179)], [(120.0, 2.6794919243112276), (120.0, 12.92820323027545)], [(140.0, 2.298981118867903)], [(160.0, 2.250827351906659)], [(180.0, 2.4999999999999996), (180.0, 6.000000000000004)], [(200.0, 3.2523178818773006), (200.0, 3.0522653889161626)], [(220.0, 5.622391569468206), (220.0, 2.226834844885431)], [(240.0, 37.32050807568848), (240.0, 1.9366857335569074)], [(260.0, 1.9181147622136665)], [(280.0, 2.1576718089133085)], [(300.0, 2.85976265663383)], [(320.0, 2.9627929206431776), (320.0, 5.162096782237789)], [(340.0, 1.4051274947736847), (340.0, 69.47032761621178)]]

dist_reduced = [reduce(lambda a, b: a if a[1]>b[1] else b, elements) for elements in dist]

print dist_reduced

>> [(0.0, 1.0), (20.0, 0.8563799085248148), (40.0, 0.8371216462519347), (60.0, 0.9282032302755089), (80.0, 7.8429970322236064), (100.0, 3.753460385470896), (120.0, 12.92820323027545), (140.0, 2.298981118867903), (160.0, 2.250827351906659), (180.0, 6.000000000000004), (200.0, 3.2523178818773006), (220.0, 5.622391569468206), (240.0, 37.32050807568848), (260.0, 1.9181147622136665), (280.0, 2.1576718089133085), (300.0, 2.85976265663383), (320.0, 5.162096782237789), (340.0, 69.47032761621178)]
```

Comment: `cond ? t : f` isn't valid Python. You're looking for `t if cond else f`.